# Securely transfer data between two iOS applications using custom URL scheme + encrypted URL query fields

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, encryption

I am going to lay out my code here and want you to tell me if my method to transfer confidential user data between two apps is secure. We take security very seriously at my firm so help me figure out if I made this right.

To start - I am using a custom URL scheme to get app A to launch app B and transmit some data between the two. When launched through a URL, app B will check the identity of app A and only use data transmitted if app A is authorized to send such data.

I take a password & username in app A, encode them into data, encrypt the data, turn the NSData description into a string and then send that in the URL request. I created an object called LaunchEkoApp that handles this using the launchEkoAppWithUsername method.

```
// This is called by my main class in App A
- (void)banishUserToOtherApp
{
    LaunchEkoApp *launcher = [[LaunchEkoApp alloc] init];
    [launcher launchEkoAppWithUsername:@"?!+=WhateverUsernameYouWant=+!?" password:@"123456"];
    @autoreleasepool {
        launcher = nil;
    }
}
```

The relevant code in the LaunchEkoApp object is below:

```
#import "LaunchEkoApp.h"
#import "NSData+AESCrypt.h"// Encrypt data for transfer between apps
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> // Used to launch URL

@implementation LaunchEkoApp

#pragma mark - Encrypt Methods

- (void) launchEkoAppWithUsername: (NSString*) username password:(NSString*) password{
    NSData *uData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[[username dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] AES256EncryptWithKey:@"superSecretPassword"]];
    NSData *pData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[[password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] AES256EncryptWithKey:@"superSecretPassword"]];

    NSString* customURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ekoeko://?U=%@&C=%@", [self formatURLArgumentString:[[[uData.description stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"]], [self formatURLArgumentString:[[[pData.description stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"]]];

    @autoreleasepool { // Release encripted data. Important!
        uData = nil;
        pData = nil;
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]];
}

#pragma mark - Decrypt Methods

-(NSString *) decryptStringFromDataDescription: (NSString *) description{
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[[[NSData data] getNSDataFromNSDataDescription:description] AES256DecryptWithKey:@"superSecretPassword"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

-(NSString *) decryptStringFromData: (NSData *) data{
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[data AES256DecryptWithKey:@"superSecretPassword"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

#pragma mark - Helper Methods

-(NSString*) formatURLArgumentString:(NSString*) theString{
    NSMutableCharacterSet * URLQueryPartAllowedCharacterSet; // possibly defined in class extension ...

    // ... and built in init or on first use
    URLQueryPartAllowedCharacterSet = [[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet] mutableCopy];
    [URLQueryPartAllowedCharacterSet removeCharactersInString:@"&+=?"]; // %26, %3D, %3F

    // then escape variables in the URL, such as values in the query and any fragment:
    NSString * escapedValue = [theString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:URLQueryPartAllowedCharacterSet];

    //[self.delegate logString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ --> %@", theString, escapedValue]];

    return escapedValue;
}

@end
```

The code I use to encrypt the username/password string NSData can be seen here (see AES256EncryptWithKey and don't worry I will be using a better encryption password in production):

```
// NSData+AESCrypt.m

#import "NSData+AESCrypt.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>

static char encodingTable[64] =
{
    'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P',
    'Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f',
    'g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v',
    'w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','+','/'
};

@implementation NSData (AESCrypt)

- (NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key{
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256 + 1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero( keyPtr, sizeof( keyPtr ) ); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof( keyPtr ) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc( bufferSize );

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt( kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesEncrypted );
    @autoreleasepool {
        key = nil;
    }

    if( cryptStatus == kCCSuccess )
    {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free( buffer ); //free the buffer
    return nil;
}

- (NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key{

    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero( keyPtr, sizeof( keyPtr ) ); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof( keyPtr ) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc( bufferSize );

    size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt( kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesDecrypted );

    @autoreleasepool {
        key = nil;
    }

    if( cryptStatus == kCCSuccess )
    {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
    }

    free( buffer ); //free the buffer
    return nil;
}

# pragma mark -

-(NSData*) getNSDataFromNSDataDescription:(NSString*) dataDescription{
    const char *ptr = [dataDescription cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableData *encryptedData = [NSMutableData data];

    while (*ptr) {
        unsigned char c1 = *ptr;
        ptr++;
        if (isalpha(c1))
            c1 = (10 + c1 - 'a')<<4;
        else if (isnumber(c1))
            c1 = (c1 - '0')<<4;
        else
            continue;
        if (!*ptr)
            break; // Shouldn't occure -- bad input
        unsigned char c2 = *ptr;
        ptr++;
        if (isalpha(c2))
            c2 = 10 + c2 - 'a';
        else if (isnumber(c2))
            c2 = c2 - '0';
        c1 = c1 | c2;
        [encryptedData appendBytes:&c1 length:1];
    }

    return encryptedData;
}

#pragma mark -

+ (NSData *)dataWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string
{
    return [[NSData allocWithZone:nil] initWithBase64EncodedString:string];
}

- (id)initWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSMutableData *mutableData = nil;

    if( string )
    {
        unsigned long ixtext = 0;
        unsigned long lentext = 0;
        unsigned char ch = 0;
        unsigned char inbuf[4], outbuf[3];
        short i = 0, ixinbuf = 0;
        BOOL flignore = NO;
        BOOL flendtext = NO;
        NSData *base64Data = nil;
        const unsigned char *base64Bytes = nil;

        // Convert the string to ASCII data.
        base64Data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        base64Bytes = [base64Data bytes];
        mutableData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:base64Data.length];
        lentext = base64Data.length;

        while( YES )
        {
            if( ixtext >= lentext ) break;
            ch = base64Bytes[ixtext++];
            flignore = NO;

            if( ( ch >= 'A' ) && ( ch <= 'Z' ) ) ch = ch - 'A';
            else if( ( ch >= 'a' ) && ( ch <= 'z' ) ) ch = ch - 'a' + 26;
            else if( ( ch >= '0' ) && ( ch <= '9' ) ) ch = ch - '0' + 52;
            else if( ch == '+' ) ch = 62;
            else if( ch == '=' ) flendtext = YES;
            else if( ch == '/' ) ch = 63;
            else flignore = YES;

            if( ! flignore )
            {
                short ctcharsinbuf = 3;
                BOOL flbreak = NO;

                if( flendtext )
                {
                    if( ! ixinbuf ) break;
                    if( ( ixinbuf == 1 ) || ( ixinbuf == 2 ) ) ctcharsinbuf = 1;
                    else ctcharsinbuf = 2;
                    ixinbuf = 3;
                    flbreak = YES;
                }

                inbuf [ixinbuf++] = ch;

                if( ixinbuf == 4 )
                {
                    ixinbuf = 0;
                    outbuf [0] = ( inbuf[0] << 2 ) | ( ( inbuf[1] & 0x30) >> 4 );
                    outbuf [1] = ( ( inbuf[1] & 0x0F ) << 4 ) | ( ( inbuf[2] & 0x3C ) >> 2 );
                    outbuf [2] = ( ( inbuf[2] & 0x03 ) << 6 ) | ( inbuf[3] & 0x3F );

                    for( i = 0; i < ctcharsinbuf; i++ )
                        [mutableData appendBytes:&outbuf[i] length:1];
                }

                if( flbreak )  break;
            }
        }
    }

    self = [self initWithData:mutableData];
    return self;
}

#pragma mark -

- (NSString *)base64Encoding
{
    return [self base64EncodingWithLineLength:0];
}

- (NSString *)base64EncodingWithLineLength:(NSUInteger)lineLength
{
    const unsigned char   *bytes = [self bytes];
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:self.length];
    unsigned long ixtext = 0;
    unsigned long lentext = self.length;
    long ctremaining = 0;
    unsigned char inbuf[3], outbuf[4];
    unsigned short i = 0;
    unsigned short charsonline = 0, ctcopy = 0;
    unsigned long ix = 0;

    while( YES )
    {
        ctremaining = lentext - ixtext;
        if( ctremaining <= 0 ) break;

        for( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        {
            ix = ixtext + i;
            if( ix < lentext ) inbuf[i] = bytes[ix];
            else inbuf [i] = 0;
        }

        outbuf [0] = (inbuf [0] & 0xFC) >> 2;
        outbuf [1] = ((inbuf [0] & 0x03) << 4) | ((inbuf [1] & 0xF0) >> 4);
        outbuf [2] = ((inbuf [1] & 0x0F) << 2) | ((inbuf [2] & 0xC0) >> 6);
        outbuf [3] = inbuf [2] & 0x3F;
        ctcopy = 4;

        switch( ctremaining )
        {
            case 1:
                ctcopy = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                ctcopy = 3;
                break;
        }

        for( i = 0; i < ctcopy; i++ )
            [result appendFormat:@"%c", encodingTable[outbuf[i]]];

        for( i = ctcopy; i < 4; i++ )
            [result appendString:@"="];

        ixtext += 3;
        charsonline += 4;

        if( lineLength > 0 )
        {
            if( charsonline >= lineLength )
            {
                charsonline = 0;
                [result appendString:@"\n"];
            }
        }
    }

    return [NSString stringWithString:result];
}
#pragma mark -
- (BOOL)hasPrefixBytes:(const void *)prefix length:(NSUInteger)length
{
    if( ! prefix || ! length || self.length < length ) return NO;
    return ( memcmp( [self bytes], prefix, length ) == 0 );
}

- (BOOL)hasSuffixBytes:(const void *)suffix length:(NSUInteger)length
{
    if( ! suffix || ! length || self.length < length ) return NO;
    return ( memcmp( ((const char *)[self bytes] + (self.length - length)), suffix, length ) == 0  );
}
```

App B then receives the encrypted NSData descriptions, converts them back to NSData objects (using the getNSDataFromNSDataDescription method in NSData+AESCrypt.m above), decrypts them (using the AES256DecryptWithKey  method in NSData+AESCrypt.m above), and makes the result into a string again. It then passes the strings to another class (_signInVC) for use in logging my user in. The code to receive the data in app B looks like this:

```
// This is the main class in App B
-(void) appLoadedThroughURLWithQuery: (NSString*) query{
    // Populate sign in fields with that and try to login

    if(_initialLoad || _activeViewController == theSignInVC){
        LaunchEkoApp *launcher = [[LaunchEkoApp alloc] init];
        [_signInVC autoLoginUserWithUsername:[launcher decryptStringFromDataDescription:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>", [[[query substringToIndex:[query rangeOfString:@"&"].location] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"U=" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" "]]] password:[launcher decryptStringFromDataDescription:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>", [[[query substringFromIndex:[query rangeOfString:@"&"].location+1] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"C=" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" "]]]];
        @autoreleasepool {
            launcher = nil;
        }
    }

    // Get username/credential
    //NSString *credential = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[[self getNSDataFromNSDataDescription:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>", [[[query substringFromIndex:[query rangeOfString:@"&"].location+1] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"C=" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" "]]] AES256DecryptWithKey:@"superSecretPassword"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];;
    //NSString *username = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[[self getNSDataFromNSDataDescription:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>", [[[query substringToIndex:[query rangeOfString:@"&"].location] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"U=" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" "]]] AES256DecryptWithKey:@"superSecretPassword"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    @autoreleasepool {
        query = nil;
    }
}
```

This sums up my code. Do you think this is a secure way to transfer the information between apps?

Other notes:

I intend to bundle my LaunchEkoApp and NSData+AESCrypt code into a library to avoid tampering with my secret encryption password. I think the buffer for the encryption is getting released because I kill the launcher object in the autoreleasepools. I don't save the final username/password strings anywhere and only assign them to some textfields that belong to the _signInVC temporarily (they are not publicly accessible and get their text set to nil once the user is done using them or app goes to background).

Comment: Notes: Don't do your own Base64, that is available in `NSData`. Don't use the description method, it is for debugging only and not guaranteed not to change. Do not use strings as an encryption key, extend them to data with PBKDF2. Use an iv, preferably a random one. Better yet use RNCryptor, it does everything needed and correctly.

Comment: Wow, perhaps a new record, one statement 576 characters long and another at 530 characters! Don't do that, it is neither maintainable nor understandable much less verifiable. Use multiple intermediate statements. Write code for the next developer to eaisly understand, not the compiler.

Comment: If you take security seriously then at a minimum get a cryptographic domain expert to consult and vet the cryptographic method and code.

Comment: I do not use the Base64 for anything, I just had it there in case you all would think it's a better idea to use. I was concerned with using an iv for a encryption key as I thought some guru might watch my memory allocations and be able to get that variable. Why shouldn't I use strings for the key? Can you elaborate on your logic there? Also these are by far the shortest classes in my code :). I write long because I am the only developer, I agree that I should simplify though.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't include code that is not needed, don't write your own when there is a version provided by Apple.
2. An iv does not need to be secret.
3. Protecting against an attacker watching memory allocation is applicable to the key and there is no defense.
4. Strings as passwords do not have enough entropy (randomness) to be secure.
5. Most of the code in the class is the Base64 implementation that is not needed and such code belongs elsewhere such in a utility class, a class should do one thing.
6. Long statements are hard to get right and mostly impossible to debug, use intermediate statements.

Without a thorough understanding of cryptographic primitives and their secure usage there is little chance of getting security correct, the best you can do is to use RNCryptor, it does everything needed and correctly.

Security is hard to get correct, at a minimum get a cryptographic domain expert to consult and vet the cryptographic method and code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! The only problem I have with apple code is that they tend to replace things instead of fixing things. So I am stuck with a leaky web view because they never fixed it and I need to support iOS 7. Sure they made a new class for newer versions of iOS, but those old versions are stuck using the old classes. Similarly their keychain management code is also bad and seems to arbitrarily lose user credentials. I don't generally trust code written by Apple as a result.